# Tabular: Package array Error: File ended while scanning use of \multicolumn

Tags: tables

I try to make a simple table with the heaser line to be red as the following example shows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht!]
        \centering
        \def\arraystretch{1.0}  
        \begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
            \hline
            \rowcolor{red}
            \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{XMPP Extention}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Usage}}} \\
                XEP-0045 & Blah Blah \\
                XEP-0049 & Blah Blah \\
                XEP-0249 & Blah Blah \\
                XEP-0055 & Blah Blah \\ 
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Whilst I try to compile it I get the following error:

> File ended while scanning use of \multicolumn.

So I wonder why I get this error.

Comment: The error is `\begin{tabular}[| c | c |]` -- it should be written as `\begin{tabular}{| c | c |}` -- note the `braces` `{}` instead of the square brackets `[]` -- you're trying to put the column definitions into the optional argument of a tabular, which is a bad idea, so there is no `{}` which has the real column definitions → LaTeX eats `\hline` in order to interpret it as column specification -- which is wrong as well

Comment: `\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{XMPP Extention}}` should be `\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{XMPP Extention}}}`.

Comment: Also, don't load the `xcolor` and `colortbl` pages independently. For maximum mutual compatibility, execute a single instruction: `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`. For more information, see p. 9 of the user guide of the `xcolor` package.

Answer (score 2):

The `tabular` environment takes an optional argument as well as a mandatory one:

```
\begin{tabular}[<vpos>]{<col spec>}
  % ...
\end{tabular}
```

You've mistakenly placed the `<col spec>` in the position of `<vpos>`. The way TeX's consumption of tokens works, it grabs `\hline` as the mandatory argument, and this doesn't have any of the expected `c`, `l`, `r` or `p` specifications. That's why it defaults to `c`.

This is probably what you're after:

```
\begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
  % ...
\end{tabular}
```

As an aside, consider using [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) and avoid using vertical rules `|`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using curly braces rather than square brackets to enclose the main argument of the `tabular` environment -- i.e., writing `{| c | c |}` instead of `[| c | c |]` -- you should

- use a single instruction, `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`, instead of loading the `xcolor` and `colortbl` packages independently;
- rethink your approach to designing the table's layout: If you wish to create a white-on-red header row, you shouldn't mix-and-(mis)match visual metaphors by using `\hline`;
- simplify the table's further by omitting all vertical bars.

Finally, I think the word in the first header cell is spelled 'Extension', not 'Extention'.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array} % for '\extrarowheight' macro
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more open "look"
\centering 
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \rowcolor{red}
    \color{white}\textbf{XMPP Extension} & 
    \color{white}\textbf{Usage} \\
    XEP-0045 & Blah Blah \\
    XEP-0049 & Blah Blah \\
    XEP-0249 & Blah Blah \\
    XEP-0055 & Blah Blah \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```